# Setting up auto-reply for Exchange Distribution Group/List?

Tags: exchange-server, reply, distribution-list

So I thought I have this setup correctly, but it is not working. Maybe someone can help?

I setup a mailbox called **formsmbx** (for FORMS MailBoX)

I setup a distribution list (DL) in Exchange 2013 named **forms**

In this DL, I added one member (**formsmbx**).

In Exchange, I setup a mail flow rule with these parameters:

```
If sender is 'outside the organization' AND the To or CC box contains forms@, 
Then bcc the message to formsmbx@.
```

I logged into a Windows computer running Outlook 2019 as **formsmbx**. I went to File/Manage Ruls & Alerts. I setup a Rule that says:

```
after message arrives
have server reply using 'auto reply'
```

So finally, I sent an email from test@gmail.com to **forms@domain.com**. What I found was the **formsmbx@** inbox receives the email, but there is never an auto-reply sent out.

If I send an email directly to **formsmbx@**, I do not get any reply.